# preg_replace and Regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, preg-replace

Could you please help me? I don't understand why do I get this error.

> Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'h'

```
$data_proces="<link>http://news.abc.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&ampkkk&amp;url=http://example.com/abc<link>  
$find_delete="<link>http:\/\/news\.abc\.com\/news\/url\?sa=.+url=";
    $replace_x="<link>";
    $data_process= preg_replace($find_delete,$replace_x, $data_process);
```

Comment: $data_proces="<link>http://news.abc.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&ampkkk&amp;url=http://example.com/abc<link>";
$find_delete="/<link>http:\/\/news\.abc\.com\/news\/url\?sa=.+url=/";
    $replace_x="<link>";
    echo $data_process= preg_replace($find_delete,$replace_x, $data_proces);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use delimiters at start and end. It is advisable to choose a character which does not occur in the pattern, for example:

```
$find_delete = "#<link>http://news\\.abc\\.com/news/url\\?sa=[^;]+;url=#";
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss delimetes in `$find_delete`. It should be:

```
$data_process="<link>http://news.abc.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&ampkkk&amp;url=http://example.com/abc<link>";
$find_delete="/<link>http:\/\/news\.abc\.com\/news\/url\?sa=.+url=/";
              ^                                                   ^
$replace_x="<link>";
echo preg_replace($find_delete,$replace_x, $data_process);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy. In PHP, you have to start and end the regex string with `/`. After the end `/` you can put some modifier flag. Read this for more understanding. http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html

So you code should be:

```
$find_delete="/<link>http:\/\/news\.abc\.com\/news\/url\?sa=.+url=/";
```